# Is it allowed in iOS - Swift Dynamic Framework - Contains Multiple Static Library

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, static-libraries, linker-errors

I have developed a framework for my customer, thats a swift dyanmic framework. For code modularization i have divided this framework features in to multiple static libraries as shown in the diagram below. Currently we have on main swift dynamnic framework and it contains 2 static libraries too. Also the first static library here in turn nested with another static library, Key points to note here is

My static libraries contains other third party iOS frameworks
My static libraries using CoccoaPods as the dependency for Alarmofire at the moment.
[image]

My questios are

Is there any problem in the current architecture , because i heard nested libraries are not supported in iOS . but since we dont have frameworks nested here, all of our second level frameworks are static libraries only.
What are link/libary search path guidance we needed to take care to make a successful build.

Comment: No you can’t put frameworks in a framework. They won’t get compiled. You can use a Swift Package.

Comment: @loremipsum I've only one swift dynamic  framework , rest all are swift static libraries inside.

Comment: It’s called an “umbrella framework” macOS is the only one that is capable of supporting it but this is a highly discouraged practice. It cannot be done for other platforms. SPM is the only solution.

Comment: are you shipping the Main Framework or the support libraries as well to your customer?

Comment: I wanted to ship only the main framework to the customer. I understand if there are nested frameworks then its umbrella framework..but in our case only one framework and rest all are static libraries . @loremipsum